# Will the Oracle forms compiled in Solaris work on Linux

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle11g, solaris, oracleforms

Anyone has an experience migrating from Solaris to Linux? May I know if the oracle forms compiled in Solaris will work on Linux Server? Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

It might, if you compile it on Linux Server.

If you just planned to copy fmx from one computer to another and hope that it'll work ... well, I don't think so. Though, it won't cost much to try it, will it?

As of compilation: you don't have to do it manually, form-by-form. Write a script which will do it for you. I don't use Linux, but quick search returned such a script, written by Arunkumar Ramamoorthy-Oracle and posted on OTN Forms forum, here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/958525?start=0&tstart=0

```
#Forms/Reports 9.0.X, 10.x
#UNIX Forms Compile
#compile_forms.sh
set ORACLE_HOME=<YOUR_ORACLE_HOME>
export ORACLE_HOME
for i in `ls *.fmb`
do
echo Compiling Form $i ....
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/frmcmp_batch.sh userid=ACCOUNT/ACCOUNT@cmt batch=no module=$i module_type=form
compile_all=yes window_state=minimize
done
```

See if it helps.